# strange behavior of Visual studio 2010 ASP.NET test server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I mainly use VS2010 and C# to develop ASP.NET web apps, although its test server is a great tool for developing web applications but sometimes I get strange behaviors, for instance sometimes I press F5 to run app, and my browser window opens (firefox is my default web browser in VS), some controls are displayed in page and suddenly I get an error, I understand that test server is not run! when I switch to visual studio I see that blue triangle icon is still active and stop/pause icons are disable (so that it may seem my program has never run!), it seems that sometimes program runs (HTML is displayed on browser) but my server is not running, what is going wrong here?

I should tell that this problem occurs in rare cases (for example once in 40 runs) and often I have several visual studio windows open (each for a separate project)

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Does this offer any joy? http://blog.syntaxc4.net/post/2010/06/15/Having-Cassini-Crash-while-using-ASPNET-MVC.aspx

Or this http://asp.net.bigresource.com/-net-Cassini-VS-WebDev-executing-BeginRequest-and-EndRequest-on-different-threads--02qr8lrLl.html

Can you try switch to IIS or IIS Express as your debugging platform and see if that helps out? Just as a proof of concept?

Comment: thanks, I though no one will answer this question! I'll take a look at them

Comment: No dramas - hope you have luck with these. Also can I ask - can you replicate this on another development machine? Sometimes it's hard to try this out - but some of these issues can be purely environmental..

Comment: yes you are right, but I've experienced this situation on several machines (laptops and PCs), I think this is because often I have several instances of Visual Studio open, and each VS uses a separate tester